# Where is the the site name and slogan set?

Tags: 7

In the page--front.tpl.php template, I have the following code for site logo.

```
<img src="<?php print $logo ?>" alt="example.com logo" title="<?php print $site_name_and_slogan ?>" id="logo" />
```

Where is the title set in Drupal 7? Right now the title is showing blank in the production site.

Comment: So I checked the site information in the configuration/system page & system info and sure enough the site name and slogan values are filled in. However in the template and then the production site, the title value is blank why so?

Comment: Is that variable a custom one? That could be why the title attribute is blank. Check the themes template.php file.

Comment: I got this in template.php file: $variables['site_name_and_slogan'] = $site_name_text . ' ' . $slogan_text;

Comment: Sounds like the variables aren’t populated correctly.

Comment: Hmm ok also when I hover the cursor over the logo in desktop view, a blank popup comes up. Shouldn't it show the value for "Alt=" ? Should I even have title setup for img src html anymore?

Comment: Ok so the title value sets the hover value. Now why is it showing blank in my page?

Answer (score 1):

In your active theme's template.php, check `template_preprocess_page()` function and add following lines:

```
$site_name = variable_get('site_name');
$site_slogan = variable_get('site_slogan');
$variables['site_name_and_slogan'] = $site_name . ' ' . $site_slogan;
```

Assuming that you have used $variables as argument in `template_preprocess_page()` function.

Now `$site_name_and_slogan` can be used in page tpl files.

If you have not implemented `template_preprocess_page()` function, then replace template word with your theme name and add the function as mentioned below:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables){
  $site_name = variable_get('site_name');
  $site_slogan = variable_get('site_slogan');
  $variables['site_name_and_slogan'] = $site_name . ' ' . $site_slogan;
}
```

Comment: Ok I shall try. Thanks so much.. the active theme function is in a file or drupal setting?

Comment: Also In Appearance section of the site's them there is a "Toggle Display" section. In it "Site Name" & "Site Slogan" are unchecked. Could this cause a problem?

Comment: Checkboxes in appearance will not cause any problem with above implementation. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have u tried these?

```
    <?php print $site_name; ?>
    <?php print $site_slogan; ?>
```

You can use it as

```
    <img src="<?php print $logo ?>" alt="example.com logo" title="<?php echo $site_name.$site_slogan; ?>" id="logo" />
```

Comment: I'll try for sure and revert back here.

Comment: Ok it now sets the title to be site_slogan doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry i had missed the $ symbol. Please check now

Comment: Thanks but the result is a blank. It didn't work.

Comment: is this a custom theme? if yes, need to see your template.php file

Comment: Yes it is custom.

Comment: why not remove ur custom variable from the template.php file. - $variables['site_name_and_slogan'] = $site_name_text . ' ' . $slogan_text; –   
 You can refer Bartik themes template.php file and set it back to the default variables

Comment: Ok I'll check this gets complicated.

Comment: Other thing is I need to find out which template.tpl.php file is being used by which view. Where are these values set in drupal 7?